# infopath in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, css, html5

Is it recommanded to use infopath in sharepoint 2013?
and please give me some links to proceed for infopath and its validation
can we write code in visual studio for same ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, he has a very difficult maintenance and is unstable. Recommend the use of HTML 5 and CSS.

Comment: HTML5 and CSS to replace all the features of InfoPath? Non of my clients would accept HTML5 at all, since they in best case have mainly IE 9 browsers (I say mainly meaning that usually there is a nice blend of IE8, IE7 etc as well). Also writing all InfoPath functionality yourself (no matter in what language) would be a huge project, which no customer will happily pay for.

Comment: Use html 4 and 5, he need check the resources. I faced many problems with infopath, Now the html such problems are eliminated.

Comment: thank you Robert and Diago for your suggestions this will defenatly help me

Comment: @RobertLindgren if I use infopath then I and myclient wants to have infopath licening to, and I am developing   the same solution for sharepoint enterprice and foundation too, and in future u may develope same solution for standerd. So what is your reconmandation for using infopath please guide me. or should i proceeds with HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: For that I recommend and always will recommend HTML5?
Because if you are developing an app or any other solution and have a web designer with little knowledge, he will have complete ease in styling your application and create the desired effects. I've had a list that used infopath, the list reached 2,000 items, at first it was a wonder (while the list was small), after the list acquired large proportion, took over an hour just to publish a tiny change in form. My opnion is, HTML 5, whoever it hurts.